# web page doesn't display chart or any error

Tags: mysql, pdo, chart.js

I just started my adventure with chartsjs. I tried to modify all tutorials I found to suit my needs, but unfortunately the page doesn't display the chart and doesn't give any errors. Can anyone advice please.

```
$result='';
$sql="SELECT Q1.uUserName AS Technician, sum(if(Q2.dCatFK=1,1,0)) AS AM,  sum(if(Q2.dCatFK=2,1,0)) as PM
FROM T_users as Q1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT dUser2FK, dCatFK FROM T_Defects 
INNER JOIN T_settings WHERE (dDateClosed >= FYDateFROM AND dDateClosed <= FYDateTO)";
if (!empty($_SESSION['dept'])) { $sql .= ' AND dDeptFK = '.$_SESSION['dept'];}
if (!empty($_SESSION['area'])) { $sql .= ' AND dAreaFK = '.$_SESSION['area'];}
if (!empty($_SESSION['month'])){ $sql .= ' AND MONTH(dDateClosed) = '.$_SESSION['month'];}
$sql .=") as Q2 ON Q1.uPK = Q2.dUser2FK GROUP BY Q1.uUserName ORDER BY sum(if(dCatFK is not null,1,0)) DESC, Q1.uUsername;";
try{
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $label = array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $label[]  = $row["Technician"];
        $data[] = $row["AM"];
        $data[] = $row['PM'];
    }

} catch(PDOException $e){
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

```
<canvas id="myChart_Fixed" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart_Fixed");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels:<?=json_encode($label);?>,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Fixed AM',
          data:<?=json_encode(array_values($data[0]));?>,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
          label: 'Fixed PM',
          data:<?=json_encode(array_values($data[1]));?>,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true
              }
          }]
      }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're appending your $data with AM and PM data so there are no 2 datasets instead there is only one dataset. Because of that $data[1] doesn't exists. Declare another 2 arrays and insert there your data for AM and PM respectively, then insert $dataAM at $data[0]... Let the code speak for itself:

**...PHP file**

```
 $data = array();
 $dataAM = array();
 $dataPM = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $label[]  = $row["Technician"];
        $dataAM[] = $row["AM"];
        $dataPM[] .=$row['PM'];
    }
 $data[0] = $dataAM;
 $data[1] = $dataPM;
```

**...HTML File**

```
 data: {
      labels:<?=json_encode($label);?>,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Fixed AM',
          data:<?=json_encode(array_values($data[0]));?>,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
          label: 'Fixed PM',
          data:<?=json_encode(array_values($data[1]));?>,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error, changed this:

json_encode(array_values($data[0]))

to this:

json_encode(array_values($data))

Comment: I rushed to find a solution, but it didn't quite worked out. The above made the chart visible but second series doesn't read its's data, it reads and displays the first series ... I still need some advice on how to display arrays correctly please